# TensorFlow device placement algorithm and graph partitioning

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

1) I have seen that unless stated otherwise, a subgraph in simple_placer.cc is placed on task 0 (mapped to device 0), but, before that, it occurs graph partitioning. So, if after this operation we have two subgraphs, then they are going to be mapped to different tasks/devices?

2) Is there a way to have automatic device placement for model parallelism considering distributed execution or should I have to set it manually? Broadly speaking, not only model parallelism, but automatic task parallelism?

Answer (score 2):

some good holiday reading on the latest research in this area:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04972

Answer (score 0):

(1) yes, if you explicitly set graph nodes on specific device, ex:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

Then `{a,b}` subgraph is on `gpu:1`, and `{c}` subgraph is on default `gpu:0`

(2) About model parallelism, programmer should claim by their own. **Auto data parallelism** seems easier. But I'm also curious about how to partition the model to achieve model parallelism benefits.